# Getting DisplayAttribute when itering on all enums of an assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to iterate through all the `enums` contained in an assembly, and for each of them, build an object which I will return to a frontend.

I can retrieve the text value of a enum item, as well as its numeric value, but I'm trying to get its `DisplayAttribute` when there is one. (ie: `[Display(Name = "Sales Admin")]` instead of `SalesAdmin`)

Here's what I have so far

```
//represents an enum, that will be consumed by the frontend
public class DataEnumItem
{
    public string EnumName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Items { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();
}

private List<DataEnumItem> ReturnDataEnumItems<T>()
{
    List<DataEnumItem> results = new List<DataEnumItem>();
    var dataEnums = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsEnum && x.IsPublic);

    foreach (var e in dataEnums)
    {
        var values = Enum.GetValues(e);

        DataEnumItem item = new DataEnumItem();
        item.EnumName = e.Name;

        foreach (var value in values)
        {    
            item.Items.Add(value.ToString(), (int)value);
        }

        results.Add(item);
    }

    return results;
}
```

So far, that works, but like I said, I wish I could get the `DisplayAttribute` on each of the enum's item if there is one.

I have a method to do that, but only when I have a property that is strongly typed. For example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    [Display(Name = "First Choice")]
    firstChoice = 0
} 

public static string GetDisplay(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var displayAttr = GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(enumValue);
    if (displayAttr != null)
        return displayAttr.Name;
    else
        return "";
}
```

Then using it:

```
MyEnum x = MyEnum.firstChoice;
string display = x.GetDisplay();
```

Is there any to retrieve the display attribute when the enum value I have is not strongly typed (ie: retrieved via `Enum.GetValues()`)

Comment: What do you mean by "not strongly typed"?

Comment: @GuruStron Retrieved via `Enum.GetValues()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast to `System.Enum` and call your `GetDisplay` method:

```
foreach (var e in dataEnums)
{
    DataEnumItem item = new DataEnumItem();
    item.EnumName = e.Name;
    item.Items = Enum.GetValues(e)
        .Cast<Enum>()
        .Select(ev => (key: ev.GetDisplay(), value: (int)(object)ev))
        .ToDictionary(ev => ev.key, ev => ev.value);
    results.Add(item);
}
```

Or just substitute you dictionary addition with:

```
item.Items.Add(((Enum)value).GetDisplay(), (int)value)
```

Or, if previous options for some reason does not work for you:

```
e.GetField(value.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes<DisplayAttribute>()
```

Comment: Ah yes, `Enum` is the base type for all enums, I forgot about that.